# Referencing one tab from another

Tags: excel

I have two sheets in my Excel file, we'll call Tab 1 and Tab 2. Tab 2 references cells on Tab 1.

I originally used things like "=Tab1!AO12". Tab 2 references these cells from Tab 1: AO12, AO13, AO15, AO18, AO22, AO23, AQ23, AS23, AO24, AO25, AQ25, AS25, AO16, AO20, AQ20, and AO21.

Instead of selecting all of these cells individually for  each section of information, I would like to specify a reference cell, and then have 'formulas' to select the remaining cells.

For example, in the top list of cells, AO12 would be the reference; the next cell would be the equivalent of (AO12 + 1), then (AO12 + 3), (AO1 2+ 6), etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: `=INDIRECT("'Tab 1'!AO"&ROW(Z12)+1)` ?

Comment: That's close. I want to reference the one cell on Tab 2 that I will use "=Tab1"AO12" for, though, so I can copy this line of referenced cells and use it for multiple references (like AO12) on Tab 1.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you are wanting to do